# Reduce top margin of itemize when inside columns environment (beamer)

Tags: beamer, margins, enumerate, itemize, description

I wrote the following example code:

```tex
\documentclass{beamer}

\usetheme{Copenhagen}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \begin{block}{Top margin is fine}
    \begin{columns}[b,onlytextwidth]
      \begin{column}{.5\textwidth}
        Left
      \end{column}
      \begin{column}{.5\textwidth}
        Right
      \end{column}
    \end{columns}
  \end{block}
  \begin{block}{Top margin is too big}
    \begin{columns}[b,onlytextwidth]
      \begin{column}{.5\textwidth}
        \begin{itemize}
          \item Left 1
          \item Left 2
        \end{itemize}
      \end{column}
      \begin{column}{.5\textwidth}
        \begin{itemize}
          \item Right 1
          \item Right 2
        \end{itemize}
      \end{column}
    \end{columns}
  \end{block}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

This code produces the following output:

[image: Example PDF output]

As you can see, in the 2nd box, there is too much margin at the top of the `itemize` environment.

Is there a simple and clean way to reduce this margin when `itemize` (`description` and `enumerate` too) is used as the first "element" of a `column` environment?